# VirtualBox - can't telnet to SMTPS service on guest machine

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, dovecot

I have Debian7 running VirtualBox v4.1.18, with a guest VM running CentOS 7 which runs Dovecot. I'm able to telnet to 995 from localhost (i.e., from the VM to itself) and other guest machines, and I can do basic auth using simple commands, but I cannot telnet from the host to the guest machine. Here is the output of

**`firewall-cmd --list-all`**

```
  public (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client imaps pop3s smtp ssh
  ports: 465/tcp 587/tcp 995/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

I also have 995 forwarded on my VirtualBox manager for this host. I can ssh into the box just fine... I can hit port 465/587... I have verified my host machine is not consuming 995... I have restarted the VM and the host machine multiple times....

Here is my `dovecot.conf`:

```
fs
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
listen = *
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

What can I to to fix this or diagnose it further?

edit:

After a restart, I have changed the host port from 995 to some other port and was able to successfully telnet to the dovecot service. I might have something on Debian7 blocking 995? Not sure...

Comment: NAT from VirtaulBox for this particular machine and port

Comment: (0) I edited your question — please check that I haven't changed the meaning.  (1) Are you using the same command to connect to your Docecot VM from the other VMs and from the host?  What is it, exactly?  (I guess `telnet the_IP_address 995`)  (2) What, exactly, happens when you issue that command on the host?  Is there an error message?  (What is it?)  (3) When you say, "I can ssh into the box just fine", do you mean that you can ssh into the VM from the host?  (00) Do not reply in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You have made correct edits. The error that I'm getting is "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused". And when I say I can ssh just fine I mean I can ssh from host to guest (meaning my port forwarding is properly setup and firewall is configure properly)